# Spring Boot ResponseEntity not Manupulating the HTTP Responses

Tags: spring, spring-boot, error-handling, httpresponse, http-response-codes

I'm having a problem with response entity exception handling. as it is seen, my response entity error is not changing the HTTP response.

My Codes

```
      public ResponseEntity<User> retriveUser(@PathVariable int id){
      Optional<User> foundUser;
      foundUser= userRepo.findById(id);
      
      if(foundUser.get()==null) {
          return new ResponseEntity<>(foundUser.get(),HttpStatus.HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
          }
      
      else {
          return new ResponseEntity<>(foundUser.get(),HttpStatus.OK);
          }    
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few errors in your code, first of all the `foundUser.get()==null` part does not enter the if block because it throw an error. You can check the [java document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#get--) to find out why you throw an error.

- It also needs to be **`HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND`** instead of `HttpStatus.HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND`.
- In the "Not Found" line, so that the `optionalUser.get()` method does not give an error; you have to remove it too.

```java
@GetMapping("/user/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<User> retrieveUser(@PathVariable int id) {
   Optional<User> optionalUser = userRepo.findById(id);
   if (!optionalUser.isPresent()) {
      return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
   } else {
      return new ResponseEntity<>(optionalUser.get(), HttpStatus.OK);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not call `get()` method if value is not present. can you try like below

```
public ResponseEntity<User> retriveUser(@PathVariable int id){
      Optional<User> foundUser = userRepo.findById(id);
      
      if(foundUser.isPresent()) {
          return new ResponseEntity<>(foundUser.get(),HttpStatus.HttpStatus.OK);
      }else {
          return new ResponseEntity<>(null,HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
          //or just return not found status code 
          //return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND); 
     }    
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the current accepted answer has all the details it needs, i have added my suggestions here please take a look.
you can get rid of `if else` block

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping(path = "users")
    static class UserController {

        private final Map<Long, UserInfo> users = new HashMap<>();

        UserController() {
            users.put(1L, new UserInfo(1L, "User 1"));
            users.put(2L, new UserInfo(1L, "User 2"));
        }

        @GetMapping(path = "{id}")
        public ResponseEntity<UserInfo> get(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
            return findUserById(id)
                    .map(ResponseEntity::ok)
                    .orElse(new ResponseEntity<>(UserInfo.notFoundUser(), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
        }

        Optional<UserInfo> findUserById(@NonNull Long id) {
            return Optional.ofNullable(users.get(id));
        }

        static class UserInfo {
            Long id;
            String name;

            public UserInfo() {
            }

            public UserInfo(Long id, String name) {
                this.id = id;
                this.name = name;
            }

            public Long getId() {
                return id;
            }

            public void setId(Long id) {
                this.id = id;
            }

            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }

            public void setName(String name) {
                this.name = name;
            }

            static UserInfo notFoundUser() {
                return new UserInfo(-1L, null);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

change your code to below

```
if(foundUser.isPresent()) {
          return new ResponseEntity<>(foundUser.get(),HttpStatus.OK);
} else {
          return new ResponseEntity<>(foundUser.get(),HttpStatus.HTTP_VERSION_NOT_SUPPORTED);
}
```

Comment: unfortunately not helped. it returns the same error.

Comment: in that case use a debugging from the IDE. Also the exception stack trace should give you more info about the error.

Comment: "java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present" written on the console